# 74HCT244 UART level translator, how would the circuit look?

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, atmel, level-shifting

I am building a UART 3.3V to 5V Level translator between a Raspberry Pi and a ATMega328.

The [74HCT244](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1886162.pdf) is my choice of translator but I can't find a good example of of hooking it up.

1. Am I right that I should power it with 3.3V(VCC)?
2. Output enabled(Grounded)
3. 3.3v TX on Input 1.This should Output 1 at 3.3V to the ATMega328 that can work with 3.3V logic.
4. 5v RX on Input 2 with Output Enabled. Connecting Output 2 at 3.3V to the RPI.

Number 4 to me is the bit I am not certain about. If I run the VCC at 3.3V will the input pins accept voltages above VCC.

Comment: Re $4 -- its clear from the table in the datasheet called "recommended operating conditions " that the maximum level of the input voltage Vi is VCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the 74HCT744, you could use a chip specially made for this, such as the TI TXB0104.  SparkFun makes a convenient [breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11771) for this chip, priced at only $4, so you don't have to deal with as SMT part.

[image]

From the SparkFun description:

> This 4-bit noninverting translator uses two separate configurable
> power-supply rails. The A port is designed to track VCCA. VCCA accepts
> any supply voltage from 1.2V to 3.6V. The B port is designed to track
> VCCB. VCCB accepts any supply voltage from 1.65V to 5.5V. This allows
> for universal low-voltage bidirectional translation between any of the
> 1.2-V, 1.5-V, 1.8-V, 2.5-V, 3.3-V, and 5-V voltage nodes. VCCA should not exceed VCCB. We have broken out each pin on this module for you to
> easily access both the A and B ports.

So you want to supply VCCA with 3.3v and VCCB with 5v.

Comment: Thanks @tcrosley. I am looking at the TXS0102. It has only two lines and cost half the price but the package is tiny but usable.

Answer (score 0):

Run it on 5 volts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHA6Hh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While using a resistive divider is not something to do with high-speed signals (due to the effects of parasitic capacitance) for UART signals you ought to be OK.